# Can you build a SQL Analysis cube from term store taxonomy and user profiles?

Tags: sql-analysis-services, user-profile-property, term-store

We are using a term store taxonomy for the company organisation and each user profile has been tagged to a organisation taxonomy item.

Now the demand is to view how many people are located in a department and all sub-departments.

Could you build a SQL Analysis cube based on a SharePoint term store taxonomy and user profile fields?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to develop a custom staging database with a star Schema and the do a timer job export or something. Do you really want a cube just for this one type of query? Unless you have other facets than just department, I would solve this a different way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris. How would you solve it? The demand is that the data is dynamically updated and thath end users can view the data in an easy way.